# how to sort a string or array of number using one loop

Tags: java, string, sorting

/*  in the program we are using only one single for loop to sort the string or array of numbers */

```
public class Sachin {
   String original="chinumaruti";
   int len=original.length();
   char ch[]=original.toCharArray();
   int i=0,j=0;
   void sorting()
   {
      for(i=0;i<original.length()-1;i++) /* for loop */
      {
         if(ch[i]<ch[i+1])
         {
            char temp=ch[i];
            ch[i]=ch[i+1];
            ch[i+1]=temp;
         }
         if(i==len-2)/* again going to intialize for loop */
         {
             i=-1;
             j++;
         }
         if(j==len-2)/* for preventing the loop to run infinite times */
         {
             System.out.println(ch);
             break;
         }
     }

 }

 public static void main(String []args){
     Sachin ob=new Sachin();
     ob.sorting();
 }
}
```

Comment: Where does your code fail?

Answer (score 1):

While this is technically a "single" loop, this is actually an implementation of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Resetting the loop iterator back to -1 is a bad practice:

```
if(i==len-2)/* again going to intialize for loop */  {
    i=-1;
    j++;
}
```

It makes your code significantly less readable and harder to follow.

The code is not more efficient than doing it in a double loop (it's still `O(n^2)`), and using a smart sorting algorithm (including the one already exists in java: [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(char[]))), will do it more efficiently and more easily.

Comment: Furthermore, it is technically impossible to sort random arrays in O(n) for now: [Sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: @crigore Not entirely correct. Note that the question asks about a `String`, or sorting array of `char`s. If we're speaking strings with fixed and relatively small character set, a bucket sort is a feasible solution, and it runs in O(n).

Comment: that's why I added the random part to the arrays, not sure of the scope of the question. Anyway, good point.